# Rust Installation on Windows for developing GUI apps

Tags: windows, user-interface, rust

### TL:DR;

Can I write GUI programs on Win 10 (64) using Rust without installing the full MinGW toolchain (nor the MS equivalent)?

<sub>Supplementary questions:</sub>

<sub>- If not, should I just go ahead and install MinGW?</sub>

<sub>- Does anything GNUish in *Windows 10 Anniversary Update* change any of this?</sub>

---

### Longer version

I [saw](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted) that Rust is the most loved programming language hereabouts so 15 minutes ago...

I [read](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/downloads.html#win-foot)

> No additional software installation is necessary for basic use of the GNU build.
>
> Rust's support for the GNU ABI is more mature, and is recommended for typical uses.

So I downloaded `Windows (GNU ABI †) (.msi) 64-bit` to my PC running Windows 10.

#### TUI

I read some basic intro and used `rustc` to compile a Hello World! and ran it OK. I then read about `cargo` and reorganised buit and ran the same code using that.

#### GUI

I then searched for `Rust GUI` and found [Kiss_UI](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/kiss-ui-a-simple-ui-tookit-for-rust/1452)

> a simple UI tookit for Rust

So I did a `cargo new Hello_GUI --bin` and added

```
[dependencies.kiss-ui]
git = "https://github.com/cybergeek94/kiss-ui"
```

to Cargo.toml

I cut and pasted a simple example from that website into main.rs

I then ran `cargo run --verbose`. It did

```
   Updating git repository `https://github.com/cybergeek94/kiss-ui`
    Updating registry `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`
 Downloading iup-sys v0.0.3
 Downloading libc v0.2.14
 Downloading libc v0.1.12
   Compiling libc v0.1.12
```

...

```
warning: crate `Hello_GUI` should have a snake case name such as `hello_gui`, #[warn(non_snake_case)] on by default
error: linking with `gcc` failed: exit code: 1
note: "gcc" "-Wl,--enable-long-section-names" ...
note: ld: cannot find -liup
error: aborting due to previous error
```

So I learned two things

- I need to use snake case.
- GUI programming is not "basic use".

I have no complaints about either of these points but could use a clue or two about the second:

Assuming I want to write a GUI equivalent of Hello World in a simple way, what are my main options now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[According to its documentation](https://github.com/KISS-UI/kiss-ui#kiss-ui-), kiss-UI depends on [the IUP library](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/).

The error from `gcc` (`can't find -liup`) suggests that you don't have IUP installed. You may be able to install it and have things work; it depends on whether the [IUP bindings used by kiss-UI](https://github.com/dcampbell24/iup-rust) can cope with windows.

Some other GUI libraries can be found at [awesome-rust](https://github.com/kud1ing/awesome-rust#gui). There are bindings to libraries like Qt and Gtk. If you know the windows API, you could also check out the [winapi crate](https://github.com/retep998/winapi-rs).

If you want to avoid messing with linking and stuff, you could try using a pure rust library like [conrod](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/conrod/), which should 'just work' on windows.

To answer your more broad questions:

See the [footnote](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/downloads.html#win-foot) on the downloads page. The MSVC version of rust depends on MSVC being installed. The GNU/MinGW build is standalone.